# Memory Corruption on using cin >>

Tags: c++

I am getting a strange memory corruption when running my code. It occurs from the "cin" in the following block. Funny thing is, the for-loop runs the first time. The momory corruption occurs on the second iteration (when i = 1).

```
case 3:
            {
                // for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS; i++)
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    mavlink_param_value_t packet_vel, packet_pwr;   
                    float vel_factor;
                    float power_factor;

                    strcpy(packet_vel.param_id, "GAME_VEL_FACTOR");
                    strcpy(packet_pwr.param_id, "GAME_PWR_FACTOR");

                    printf("Current index %d\n", i);
                    // cout << "\n" << "Enter Game Velocity Factor:";
                    // cin >> packet_vel.param_value;
                    cout << "\n" << "Enter Game Power Factor:";
                    cin >> power_factor;

                    printf("Assigning local variable to struct member\n");
                    packet_pwr.param_value = power_factor;

                    printf("Packing current message\n");
                    mavlink_msg_param_value_pack((uint8_t)i,
                                                 1,
                                                 &messages[i],
                                                 packet_vel.param_id, 
                                                 packet_vel.param_value, 
                                                 packet_vel.param_type,
                                                 1,
                                                 1);
                }

                *cont_mode = true;
                break;
```

The following is error:

```
Enter message for player 0
Current index 0

Enter Game Power Factor:1
Assigning local variable to struct member
Packing current message
Current index 1

Enter Game Power Factor:2
*** Error in `./send_mavlink_msgs': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000000ccf050 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Thank you!

Update:

Here is how I am creating "messages"

```
    mavlink_message_t *messages = (mavlink_message_t *)malloc(num_of_robots*sizeof(mavlink_global_position_int_t));
```

It's definition is found [here](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/include/mavlink/v1.0/mavlink_types.h#L103)

Comment: "memory corruption" almost always should be read as "I tried to do what you told me, but the memory _was already corrupted and I could not do it_."  That means `cin>>` is not the error, something that happened _before_ that is the error.  Since the corruption was detected by `malloc`, 99% of the time that means you accidentally wrote past the end of a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: You need to put an `endl` instead of `\n` in those `cout`s, otherwise output buffering is going to give you the wrong idea about where the error is occurring.

Comment: What is `messages`? Please show how you initialize that variable.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of C-style strings ( a.k.a. `char *`).  The C-style strings are the basis for most memory corruption, stack overflows or segmentation faults.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the suggestion. I totally forgot about it. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I made sure I cleaned my source directory free of binaries.

Comment: Beware of using local variables when sending data (a.k.a. transmitting packets).  The system may be sending packet 1 while your program is overwriting the same buffer.  Maybe you should wait for the first message to be sent before sending a second.

Comment: Dare I ask why you're even `malloc`-ing in the first place? This is tagged C++. For whatever reason John removed his answer, yet his assessment that you're already overrunning your structure members seems sound on its own merit, if not the actual problem. `param_id` is `int8_t[15]`, and `"GAME_VEL_FACTOR"`, including the terminator is **16** octets. Likewise with the second id.

Comment: @WhozCraig as per param_id, I think it is actually char[16] - https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/#PARAM_REQUEST_READ.

Comment: @WhozCraig the entire code base was written with some .c and .cpp. I may be wrong, but that's how a message gets created. I will check.

Comment: @b1gtuna it would seem we have conflicting documentation, but who knows. at this point. You could always verify in your actual source code header file you're using. It looks like John may resurrect his answer shortly with additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mavlink_message_t *messages = (mavlink_message_t *)
   malloc(num_of_robots*sizeof(mavlink_global_position_int_t));
```

This should probably be:

```
mavlink_message_t *messages = (mavlink_message_t *)
   malloc(num_of_robots*sizeof(mavlink_message_t));
```

Using the wrong `sizeof` parameter will allocate the wrong amount of space. This is a serious problem if `mavlink_global_position_int_t` is smaller than `mavlink_message_t` (which, from my cursory googling, appears to be the case).

---

Also, I'm not familiar with whatever "mavlink" is, but judging from [here](http://mikrokopter.de/mikrosvn/Projects/C-OSD/arducam-osd/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/include/mavlink/v0.9/common/mavlink_msg_param_value.h):

```
typedef struct __mavlink_param_value_t
{
 int8_t param_id[15]; ///< Onboard parameter id
 float param_value; ///< Onboard parameter value
 uint16_t param_count; ///< Total number of onboard parameters
 uint16_t param_index; ///< Index of this onboard parameter
} mavlink_param_value_t;
```

`param_id` is a 15-byte array. `"GAME_VEL_FACTOR"` and `"GAME_PWR_FACTOR"` are both 16-byte strings if you count the `'\0'` terminators at the ends.

Comment: +1 or use the common alternative, `num_of_robots  * sizeof(*messages)` for the size, which will work unless a type-punning is purposely underway. Nice assessment, btw (not surprisingly).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how my two previous cases worked with this error.